# Oci8_12.dll error "No Driver Found"

Tags: php, oracle

I have serious problem connecting Oracle (v 12c) database with php (pdo). I have IIS with PHP 7.2 version(x64). It runs .php extensions, no problem there. When i create instanse from my class i get "No Driver Found" Error. I guess my problem is not my code, but if you want to see, my code will be below my post.

I Know the problem, my problem is instantclient_12_2... I downloaded several times, i build path from Environment, it doesnt work. I remove Php 7.2 (x64) and i installed PHP 7.2 (x86), i downloaded instantclient_12_2(x32) then i build path again... But i never succeed.

And yes, i have added php_oci8.12.dll to my php.ini file, and yes, i restart my IIS several times, but it never worked! I Always get same error.

**PHP Code**

```
class PDOConnection {

private $dbh;

function __construct() {
    try {

        $server         = "193.255.1.98"; //remote
        $db_username    = "SYSTEM";
        $db_password    = "Oracle_1";
        $service_name   = "ORCL";
        $sid            = "ORCL";
        $port           = 1521;
        $dbtns          = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = $service_name) (SID = $sid)))";

        //$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".dbname, $db_username, $db_password);

        $this->dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $dbtns . ";charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function select($sql) {
    $sql_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sql_stmt->execute();
    $result = $sql_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}

public function insert($sql) {
    $sql_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    try {
        $result = $sql_stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        trigger_error('Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    if ($result) {
        return $sql_stmt->rowCount();
    }
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->dbh = NULL;
}
```

}

$dbh = new PDOConnection();

$dbh->select($select_sql);
$dbh->insert($insert_sql);

Comment: After sorting out your confusion between OCI8 and PDO_OCI (see the other answer), check you have the correct VS 2013 Redistributable installed.  The Instant Client download page has a link for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is my solution. I tried everything except install VS 2013 Redistributable! I installed it too but that was x64. After i installed x86, problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

[PDO](http://php.net/PDO) has nothing to do with `php_oci8.12.dll`. [OCI8](http://php.net/OCI8) is an entirely different extension. Please note you'll possibly have both in `php.ini`, enabled or not:

```
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=pdo_oci
```

At the time of writing, both OCI8 extension and Oracle driver for PDO are officially maintained by Oracle Corporation ([source](https://developer.oracle.com/languages/php.html)), so using either should be fine. In the past, the PDO driver was community-driven and it was unfinished and abandoned. From [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf#page=29) (PDF from 2012):

> Oracle does not contribute to PDO_OCI.
>
> The PHP community has let the PDO project languish and Oracle recommends using OCI8
> instead whenever possible because of its better feature set, performance, reliability and
> stability. Use of PDO_OCI for general purpose applications is
> not
> recommended. However PDO
> is used by some frameworks and higher level packages, such as content management
> systems so you may need to use it.

There're also [third-party libraries](https://packagist.org/?query=pdo%20oci8) with pure PHP implementations of a PDO-compatible driver on top of OCI8 but I don't have first hand experience with any.

Comment: Oracle does maintain PDO_OCI now.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Oh, that's great news indeed.